# Div Transitions - IE vs. others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JSFiddle that displays a series of boxes. If one of the boxes is clicked, it expands to cover the other boxes, then displays text. When the now expanded box is clicked, it retracts to its original width and height. This javascript works flawlessly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. However, in Internet Explorer (v10), the box expands but fails to retract. Any Insight on why this may be?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QBdDE/

Javascript:

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;            
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
       $('.overlay-text').hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
        setTimeout(function(){$('.overlay-text').show();},1000);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;

});
```

Comment: I haven't got IE10 to test on but you can remove the need for JS to change the z-indexes if you set it in the css. http://jsfiddle.net/QBdDE/3/

Comment: Did a quick check, couldn't find out what exactly goes wrong but I noticed that the `clicked` class was not removed from the div when I clicked it the second time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the retract in Firefox is a little funky with your jsfiddle. Also, it didn't work in IE10. Did you try IE11? I'm curious on the result, unfortunately my work wont let us update to 11 yet.

Comment: @ivarni Does the toggle in the Js show/hide it?

Comment: On IE11, there's an odd effect where during animation the box is 1px too far inside, so the other boxes are visible until animation stops.

Comment: I think the issue that I saw is because it's being placed from the left, and margin-left is pushing them over to the side. The width and that margin are both being animated, making it flicker. Same thing on Chrome. Probably unrelated to OP's question though.

Comment: @user3087325 Not sure what you mean by that. My observation was that after clicking the box again, the class was not removed. I didnt fetch the debugger to see what was happening. I am not at a computer with IE10 right now though, but you should be able to observe the same. Might be worth investigating wether it is toggled twice somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What's Going On

### Problem:

`pointer-events` support was added in IE11. IE10 is ignoring this, and because your overlay is on top, the mouse is interacting with it. We can get around this though!

### Solution:

We need to remove dependency on that CSS rule. To do this, we need to do two things:

1.) We need to make the hover color stays applied even if the `:hover` effect isn't happening. We can add another selector to our CSS so that the `.clicked` class will cause the colors.

2.) We need to address what happens when `.overlay_text` is clicked, and use that to trigger the shrinking animation.

---

## Code

### 1.) Hover Effect

We need to add in another select to every place `:hover` is used:

#### Old CSS:

```
.first_box:hover {

   ...background color rule ...

}
```

#### New CSS:

```
.first_box:hover, .first_box.clicked {

   ...background color rule ...

}
```

Duplicate the above for all 4 box rules.

### 2.) `.overlay-text` Trigger

We need to cause a click on `.overlay-text` to trigger the shrinking.

#### Old JS:

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;            
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
       $('.overlay-text').hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
        setTimeout(function(){$('.overlay-text').show();},1000);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ;

});
```

#### New JS:

We have to add a new selector to the `.on()` code, then we have to add `.clicked` to both the selected square, add the overlaying section. Finally we have to remove `.clicked` from both. We can't use `.toggleClass()` because we are adding to `$(this)` and removing from all `div`s.

```
$('div, .overlay-text').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        setTimeout(function (div) {
            return function () { div.css('z-index', '') ; } ;            
        } ($(this)), 1000) ;
       $('.overlay-text').hide();
       $('div').removeClass('clicked');
       $('.overlay-text').removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('z-index', 400) ;
        setTimeout(function(){$('.overlay-text').show();},1000);
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $('.overlay-text').addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

---

## Summary

I've tested in IE10 and it works.

#### Working Example: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

---

## Extra

If I may say, the CSS structure you are using could be improved and your animations will look a lot better. Chrome and IE both flicker during the animation of the two left blocks.

This is because their width AND position is being animated. If you position them from `right:0`, only their width will animate and it'll look a lot smoother.

I've created a Fiddle for you to address the above. I used absolute positioning. The CSS ends up being shorter, but mainly the animation doesn't flicker. Take a look:

#### Working Example: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

## Extra 2

As per comments from OP, we are going to prevent users from double clicking. Since all animations take 1 second, we will disable clicking from triggering anything for 1 second after each click.

It's actually pretty simple to do. In the Extra 1 above, we cleaned up the JS, and it became this:

```
$('div, .overlay-text').on('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
       $('.overlay-text').hide();
       $('div').removeClass('clicked');
       $('.overlay-text').removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){$('.overlay-text').show();},1000);
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $('.overlay-text').addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

We just need to add a global variable that starts true. When once the click happens, set it to false immediately, and after 1 second, set it to true. Then we just check to see if it's true, and don't do anything at all if it's false:

```
var notdouble = 1;
$('div, .overlay-text').on('click', function (e) {
    if (notdouble) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
           $('.overlay-text').hide();
           $('div').removeClass('clicked');
           $('.overlay-text').removeClass('clicked');
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function(){$('.overlay-text').show();},1000);
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
            $('.overlay-text').addClass('clicked');
        }
        notdouble=0;
        setTimeout(function(){notdouble=1;},1000);
    }
});
```

#### Working Example: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Note, this builds from the new structure in the Fiddle version 13, so it won't work exactly with the fixed version of the original structure. The concept can be adapted though.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for the time and effort. One more question if you don't mind, if you double click a square the text still displays, is there a way for the overlay text to "abort" if te square is clicked again?

Comment: Glad I could help! And yet it can be done. We need to put things in a timer that will ignore input for 1s. I'll fiddle around with it. What are your thoughts on the bonus fiddle with the restructuring? The JS there is simpler, and it would be easier to work from that to prevent the double click. If you are constrained to use the original though, I can try to get that to work without double clicks.

Comment: I don't mind which JS you use. I'm a beginner at JS so I'm sure my code was not too efficient

Comment: Alrighty, take a look. It prevents double clicking (or triple) from affecting it.

Comment: Again, glad to help. This is a pretty cool effect you've created. When you end up using it in a production site, drop a link here so I can check it out.

Comment: Will do, it's for a timeline where each box represents a different year

Comment: Hey Andy, everything is looking great on my site except for one small thing.....ie8. Do you know o a way to make this work in ie8?

Comment: That's not going to be pleasant. With IE9-10, it's one specific rule that is the issue. With IE7-8, we are looking at a whole host of problems. You're going to have to use JS to make it animate.

Answer (score 1):

Not working in IE 9 as the div click event never fires. I think it's covered by the section with class="overlay-text". But I've got a workaround by handling the click event of the section and triggering the div click event

```
$('section').on('click', function (e) { 
    $('.overlay-text').hide();
    $( "div" ).addClass('clicked') ;
    $( "div" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```